# Why doesn't the JMX Exporter add Tomcat metrics?

Tags: java, jmx-exporter

I am using a config like this:

```
---
hostPort: localhost:5555
username: 
password: 

rules:
- pattern: ".*"
```

This config is launched with the following parameters:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.15.0.jar=9404:config.yaml -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5555 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/camunda"
```

As I understand it, all metrics should appear with such a template, but I do not have metrics associated with tomcat and catalina.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your project's environment is tho,
but if your project is on SpringBoot and its version is over 2.2,
then how about coding the way below?

```
java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.15.0.jar=9404:config.yaml -jar yourProject.jar \
--server.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled=true\
```

If SpringBoot's version is over 2.2, you have to set `server.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled=true` to expose Tomcat metrics.